# Array out of bounds but im not sure why?

Tags: java, arrays

So this is the double array that im using

```
public int[][] MAP = { { 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 },
        { 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 },
        { 8, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 },
        { 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 },
        { 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 },
        { 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 },
        { 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 },
        { 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 },
        { 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8 },
        { 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8 },
        { 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8 },
        { 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8 },
        { 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8 },
        { 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8 },
        { 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8 } };
```

My problem is that when i try to use it to load the corresponding image, i get an error saying that it is out of bounds when y = 12.

```
Image[][] displayedMap = new Image[MAP[0].length][MAP.length];

    public Town() {
        System.out.println("Map len" + MAP.length);
        for (int x = 0; x < MAP[0].length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < MAP.length; y++) {
                System.out.println("X:" + x + ",Y:" + y);
                setImageContent(x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setImageContent(int x, int y) {
        Terrain t = Terrain.getTerrainFor(MAP[x][y]);
        displayedMap[x][y] = t.getImage();
    }
```

Its when the y turns to 11 in the town constructor and then goes to the setImagecontent that it says

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have an array column length of 11, but a row length of 15. You have flipped your array references, and so are getting an exception since the rows and columns are of different lengths.

Try this instead:

```
Image[][] displayedMap = new Image[MAP[0].length][MAP.length];
public Town() {
    System.out.println("Map len" + MAP.length);
    for (int x = 0; x < MAP.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < MAP[0].length; y++) {
            System.out.println("X:" + x + ",Y:" + y);
            setImageContent(x, y);
        }
    }
}

private void setImageContent(int x, int y) {
    Terrain t = Terrain.getTerrainFor(MAP[x][y]);
    displayedMap[x][y] = t.getImage();
}
```

Notice I'm using `MAP.length` as the limit for `x` and `MAP[0].length` as the limit for `y` now.

You've just got your x and y flipped. X is the number of rows, Y the number of columns.

Might I also suggest you check out [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/). Its a much easier way of doing this sort of thing. No more coding tiled maps into source files by hand! Edit them in a nice program, then just parse the data file in. There are many different formats, and parsers.

Comment: i set the length to the MAP.length which in this case is 15 so it would be 0-14

Comment: Right, but the indices are flipped. See the change I made?

Comment: Thanks for removing the downvotes whoever removed them. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

You have the dimensions of your array swapped, in a part of your you're using the size of the "X axis" for the Y and vice-versa

Answer (score 1):

This is how the `displayedMap` array should be created:

```
Image[][] displayedMap = new Image[MAP.length][MAP[0].length];
```

In your code, the dimensions are inverted.

Comment: Or you can flip the index references.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int x = 0; x < MAP.length; x++) {
   for (int y = 0; y < MAP[0].length; y++) {

    }
}
```

`MAP.length` is the number of rows.
`MAP[0].length` is the number of columns in that row.

Answer (score 0):

I've took the habit of reversing x and y when using bi-dimensionnal arrays, i.e. I access them by `MAP[y][x]`: you access the "line" first (the inner array), then the "column" (the item in the inner array).

If you often make the mistake, reason with "boxes containing more boxes" rather than with a single "matrix".